# OnClick for material UI components is not working in React Js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI components in my project. OnClick is not working for button. I have search on google also but didn't find any solution. I have tried using div also but that is also not working.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import MobileDrawer from "./MobileDrawer";
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    title: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        marginLeft: "20px",
        marginTop: "8px"
    },
}));

export default function MobileHeader() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const handleDrawerStatus = () => {
        alert("hi")
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static" style={{ backgroundColor: "#040b2d" }}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="open drawer"
                        edge="start"
                        onClick={handleDrawerStatus}
                    >
                        <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please show `codesandbox`, I saw everything works fine

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sunset-3u94h?file=/src/App.js
I test with `codesandbox`, it's ok. Maybe the problem comes from other components

Comment: Calling from App component. 

import React from 'react';
import Header from "./component/Header";
import MobileHeader from "./component/Header.Mobile";
import AppRoutes from "./component/AppRoutes";
import "./App.css";
import { isMobile } from "react-device-detect";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <MobileHeader />
                <AppRoutes />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default App
@LioAslan

Comment: Can you edit that line to `onClick={() => {console.log('sth'); handleDrawerStatus(); }}` and check whether it shows any log
`

Comment: @LioAslan in index.html i have removed <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script> . now working fine. thanks